# Mandatory field on inherited model - Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I've inherited `res.partner` model, now, I want to make the `vat` field, as `required` and `unique`.

I know how to do this normally, on a new model for example, but I want the original field to have these attributes.

How can I achieve this?

I think it should be on the view, but I'm not really sure, I don't think it could be done on a easy way via python.

For the uniqueness, I've tried like this:

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.partner'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    fields...
    methods...

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('vat_company_uniq', 'unique(company_id, vat)', '¡ El RIF debe ser único por compañia !'),
    ]
```

But it doesn't works, I mean, what I don't see, is the fact that this field already exists in original object, so how to "modifiy" it in order to be `unique` and `mandatory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove *_name = 'res.partner'* and use only *_inherit = 'res.partner'*.

Afterward, we have to redeclare *vat* field with *required=True* attribute in *.py* side.

*_sql_constraints* is good.

Restart Odoo server and upgrade your module. It will work fine.

Comment: Odedra, Thank You, but the sql_constraint doesn't do anything, idk, but really tried and nothing, will it need some function on it?

Comment: @NeoVe that's strange. Seems everything correct in *_sql_contraints* Might be following link will be useful in future. https://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2014/12/how-to-create-constraints-in-openerp.html

Comment: I think the problem is that I already have records on the database. I've seen other similar questions and everything seems to be Okay

Answer (score 1):

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    vat = fields...(required=True) //just specify the required attributes

    # but here i don't think it will work because the framework will not be able
    # to add this constrains because it has some duplicated value all ready like null
    # in order to make this work you need to run a query to modify old values then restart the server than odoo should be able to add this constraint check log message to see if the constraint is added
    _sql_constraints = [
        ('vat_company_uniq', 'unique(company_id, vat)', '¡ El RIF debe ser único por compañia !'),
    ]
```

Comment: Thank You, yes, but the sql_constraint isn't working, it doesn't do anything

Comment: SHould there be a function? I mean, from what I know, it should work, but it doesn't check anything, I can create the same vat over n number of companies, the required vat works though

Comment: sql_constrains odoo will try to add them to the database but i think you all ready have duplicated values so the constraint cannot be added so odoo will never catch this exception thrown by the database so the error message will never happen try to fix the duplicated values tell me if this is the problem i would know if this is the problem that you have